# R: How to identify the first occurrence of a specific value of a variable grouped by ID

Tags: r

I have a dataset in form of a Diary - i.e. i have multiple entries for the same ID. Apart from that, I have a categorical variable (Yes/no) that indicates whether the event occured or not.

```
ID <-  c(1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3)
event <- c("No", "No", "No", "Yes", "No", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "No", "Yes", "Yes") 
df <- data.frame(ID, event)

ID   event   
 1    No
 1    No
 1    No
 2    Yes
 2    No
 2    No
 2    Yes
 3    Yes
 3    Yes
 3    No
 3    No
 3    Yes
 3    Yes
```

I now want to delete those entries until the first "No", so every ID should start with a "No". However, after the first "No" there can still be a "Yes". So the desired output i want is:

```
ID   event   
 1    No
 1    No
 1    No
 2    No
 2    No
 2    Yes
 3    No
 3    No
 3    Yes
 3    Yes
```

Does anybody know how to achieve this? Thanks in advance for your time!

Answer (score 2):

We can get the first `"No"` using `which.max` and select all the rows from there till last row.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(ID) %>% slice(which.max(event == 'No') : n())
#Also
#df %>% group_by(ID) %>% slice(which(event == 'No')[1] : n())

#      ID event
#   <dbl> <chr>
# 1     1 No   
# 2     1 No   
# 3     1 No   
# 4     2 No   
# 5     2 No   
# 6     2 Yes  
# 7     3 No   
# 8     3 No   
# 9     3 Yes  
#10     3 Yes
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  filter(cumsum(event == 'No') >= 1)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 10 x 2
# Groups:   ID [3]
      ID event
   <int> <fct>
 1     1 No   
 2     1 No   
 3     1 No   
 4     2 No   
 5     2 No   
 6     2 Yes  
 7     3 No   
 8     3 No   
 9     3 Yes  
10     3 Yes
```

Answer (score 2):

An option using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .(event=event[match("No", event):.N]), ID]
```

Answer (score 2):

In *base* you can use `match` to find the position of the first `"No"`. To make this per `ID` you can use `split` and `lapply`. To put the result back in a `data.frame` you can use `rbind` with `do.call`.

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(split(df, df$ID), function(x) {
  x[match("No", x$event):nrow(x),]}))
#     ID event
#1.1   1    No
#1.2   1    No
#1.3   1    No
#2.5   2    No
#2.6   2    No
#2.7   2   Yes
#3.10  3    No
#3.11  3    No
#3.12  3   Yes
#3.13  3   Yes
```